# Finding correct index value for matrix in Matlab using meshgrid

Tags: matlab, indexing

I'm trying to build make a code where an equation is not calculated for some certain values. I have a meshgrid with several values for x and y and I want to include a for loop that will calculate some values for most of the points in the meshgrid but I'm trying to include in that loop a condition that if the points have a specified index, the value will not be calculated. In my second group of for/if loops, I want to say that for all values of i and k (row and column), the value for z and phi are calculated with the exception of the specified i and k values (in the if loop). What I'm doing at the moment is not working...

The error I'm getting is: 
`The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.`

Here is my code at the moment. I'd really appreciate any advice on this! Thanks in advance

```
U_i = 20;            
a = 4;               

c = -a*5;            
b = a*10;           
d = -20;             
e = 20;               

n = a*10;           

[x,y] = meshgrid([c:(b-c)/n:b],[d:(e-d)/n:e]');

for i = 1:length(x)
    for k = 1:length(x)
        % Zeroing values where cylinder is
        if sqrt(x(i,k).^2 + y(i,k).^2) < a
            x(i,k) = 0; 
            y(i,k) = 0;
        end 
    end
end

r = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);  
theta = atan2(y,x);
z = zeros(length(x));
phi = zeros(length(x));

for i = 1:length(x)
    for k = 1:length(x)
         if (i > 16 && i < 24 && k > 16 && k <= length(x))
             z = 0;
             phi = 0;
         else
             z = U_i.*r.*(1-a^2./r.^2).*sin(theta);         % Stream function   
             phi = U_i*r.*(1+a^2./r.^2).*cos(theta);        % Velocity potential 
         end
    end
end
```

Comment: You need to use `==` for logical statements, not `=`. That being said, the `if` statement in that position is not going to work, it needs to be expanded (e.g. `i > a && i < b && k > c && k < d` or whatever). In the future please post the full error message and stack trace to make it easier for others to locate problem areas.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to rewrite that if statement? I did have logical statements originally but as that wasn't working either so I guess I changed it! Edited the post to include them now.

Comment: I edited my original comment, probably as you were typing. How to rewrite it depends on the intent of the loop.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for that. The code runs now but it doesn't seem to be keeping those specific values at zero..

Comment: Use [the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-178) to walk through your code

Comment: Ok that's not that useful, unfortunately. I am debugging but cannot see why it is not saving these values correctly.

Comment: Of course it's useful. If you actually pay attention to what `z` is doing you'll notice you're setting it to a 1x1 array equal to 0 and then overwriting it with your grid as soon as `i` and `k` move outside of their thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

The original code in the question can be rewritten as seen below. Pay attention in the line with `ind(17:24,:)` since your edit now excludes 24 and you original question included 24.

```
U_i = 20;            
a = 4;               

c = -a*5;            
b = a*10;           
d = -20;             
e = 20;               

n = a*10;           

[x,y] = meshgrid([c:(b-c)/n:b],[d:(e-d)/n:e]');

ind = find(sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2) < a);
x(ind) = 0;
y(ind) = 0;

r = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);  
theta = atan2(y,x);

ind = true(size(x));
ind(17:24,17:length(x)) = false;

z = zeros(size(x));
phi = zeros(size(x));
z(ind)   = U_i.*r(ind).*(1-a^2./r(ind).^2).*sin(theta(ind));   % Stream function   
phi(ind) = U_i.*r(ind).*(1+a^2./r(ind).^2).*cos(theta(ind));   % Velocity potential
```

Comment: Thanks, this nearly works but I'm not sure how to adjust the rows because now it's making everything all rows after column 17 zero but I need to keep all of the values except in rows 17-24

Comment: The code now makes sure that rows 17 to 24 (including bounds) gets zero and that columns 17 to 41 (including bounds) gets zero. 41 because that is `length(x)`. Maybe you have a side-effect because you zero-out `x` and `y` at some values in the first place. Then `r` is zero and therefore `z` and `phi` as well.

Comment: Ok but this doesn't quite work still because it's putting every column and row after 17 to zero. I need to keep the values in all columns and rows up until the specified area. Imagine an area 5 or 6 rows down and extending to the end of the domain but the rest of the values (in the rest of the rows in those columns) should still be calculated. I'm not sure how to modify your suggestion to correct this

Comment: @user3460758: I'm not sure what you mean exactly... Look at the picture [here](http://i.imgur.com/fCbY0ae.png) and tell me which principle is the one you want. `1` means that the values get calculated. `0` means that the value will stay zero without calculation. If the correct principle is not on the list, please send me an example.

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry for the delay but none of those is quite what I'm looking for.. here's the link to what I mean http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=57271dd

Comment: @user3460758 No problem for the delay... I just edited the answer, so it does what you want according to the picture in the comment.

Comment: Hmmm ok that doesn't do it either... that's just putting all columns in rows 17 to 24 to zero and all values for all rows and columns to zero after column 16. I need to keep the values in all columns before the circle and all values except for in the rows "behind" the circle

Comment: @user3460758 Yes, that's the result like it has been in the picture you commented. Since I don't know what happens after the generation of `z` and `phi`, I can't do more at this point. But if you edit your question to include some more detail, I could provide further help.

Comment: Hi Matt, not quite... In the image I sent you, all values are calculated except for all columns after the circle and just the rows that fall within the diameter of the circle (there's a rectangle of non-calculated values all after the placement of the circle)... For now, I'm just trying to correctly generate z and phi so follow the area outside of those rows and columns mentioned (I think in the original post it is rows 18:24 and columns 17:end (but just for those rows). Does this make a bit more sense? Thanks again for your help!